# no module named scrapy when open scrapy project in pycharm

Tags: python, scrapy, pycharm

I'm following this [Scrapy Tutorial](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html).

I have generated the Scrapy project, but when i open the project in PyCharm 
I'm getting

> no module named scrapy

error on `import scrapy`:

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "quotes"

def start_requests(self):
    urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/',
    ]
    for url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):
    page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
    filename = 'quotes-%s.html' % page
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.body)
    self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```

I'm new to Python, I'm not quite sure what I'm missing.

Here are my settings:

[image]

Comment: take settings and select correct the python environment in which you have installed scrapy

Answer (score 0):

Screenshot of what @Albin mentioned in the comment.

[image: Way to select python interpreter for a project in pycharm]

Comment: i add a image of my settings, i do have scrapy in it but im still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with your configuration.

*Uninstall* Scrapy (select it and click the red `-`), and then *install it again* (with the green `+`).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble when i started with Scrapy, so i solved that just using pycharm.

1. I configure my source directory, where i will put the scrapy project. I created a new pycharm project and then create 'src' dir to put scrapy project.
   [Create src dir](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imPXn.png)
2. I created my scrapy tutorial project into src dir.
   [Creat scrapy tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJw6K.png)
3. In settings project install a Scrapy package.
   [Install scrapy package - 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZReE.png)
   [Install scrapy package - 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXUlE.png)
4. In `Menu > Run > Edit` configurations... Config scrapy run cmdline
   [Edit run config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ilBv.png)

   - Put (Script path) for that, you need to know where is scrapy installed, in my case it is into `/root/PycharmProjects/Spideys/venv/bin/scrapy`
   - Put (Parameters) crawl quotes
   - Put the (Working directory) in my case is the root scrapy project into pycharm src project `/root/PycharmProjects/Spideys/venv/src/tutorialMayistik/tutorialMayistik`
   - Select `Show command line afterwards`...Apply and OK.

FINALLY RUN SPIDEY!

Please! excuse my english, i'm just learning...

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had two versions of pythons installed, Scrapy was installed on 3.5 and it was in path usr/local/bin instead of usr/bin where other versions were installed. So in project settings , I had to only give the path of correct interpreter 
File -> Settings - > Project Interpreter -> Show all interpreters - > Give the correct path and apply.